# c++ how to remotely call a console window within opengl program

Tags: c++, console, keyboard

What I am trying to do is make a graphing calculator that takes certain character inputs to transform the graph, but in order to do that I need to be able to generate a console window within the program. Is there any way in c++ to do that?

using Dev C++

Comment: Why does it have to be a "console" window? Why not simply add a text-box input field to your program? It could be added in a new windows as well if that's what you want.

Comment: Guess that would work just as well.

Answer (score 0):

> but in order to do *that* I need to be able to generate a console window
>   within the program [...]

If by *that* you mean:

> takes certain character inputs

then **no, you dont *need to be able to generate a console window***. This being titled *opengl program*, a better fitting solution is to register keyboard callbacks for *the current window* ([see here under *glutKeyboardFunc*](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/docs/api.php#WindowCallback)) and handle everything through there. Other callbacks, for mouse, etc. are documented there as well.

There's no problem [downloading *freeglut*](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/index.php#download) (preserves same API and extends GLUT) in case you're missing any header(s)/libraries. Using Dev C++ is not a limiting factor for doing so.

Comment: Dev c++ doesn't have the glut.h header file. Would any other have a function like that?

Comment: @DradenMerenox OK no problem I've edited the answer with instructions to get any missing headers for your opengl application code.

Answer (score 0):

For the purpose that I've submitted, you don't need to call a console. If you don't want to use the glut method above, what you can do instead is use a few functions present in the windows.h header file to take inputs.

The best way to implement inputs without glut involves creating a thread in your program that takes the inputs, and modifies a few variables that the main thread can use. Lets take a simple program here as an example:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <pthread.h>

//the thread that takes the inputs
void * takeInputs(void * outputVariable)
{
    //casts the output type so the compiler won't complain about setting void* to something
    char * output = (char*) outputVariable;
    //generic loop to stay alive
    while (1 == 1) {
        //checks to see if the key is in the on state, by getting only the needed bit in the data.
        //In this case, we're checking to see if the A key on the keyboard is pressed
        //You can use different keys like the arrow keys, using VK_UP VK_RIGHT
        if (GetAsyncKeyState('A') & 0x8000 != 0)
        {
            *output = 1;
        }
    //put a delay in here so that the input doesn't consume a lot of cpu power
    Sleep(100);
    }
    pthread_exit(0);
}



int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int iCmdShow)
{
    //DoUnimportantWindowsSetup
    char option = 0;
    pthread_t Inputs;
    //order: pointer to handle, Pointer to thread output, pointer to function, pointer to input
    pthread_create(&Inputs, NULL, takeInputs, &option);

    //Do stuff

    if (option == 1) doWorks();
    else doNotWorks();


    //Order: thread handle, pointer to variable that stores output
    pthread_join(Inputs, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```